# Ridge regression model using cross validation technique and Grid-search technique

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, cross-validation, grid-search

I created python code for ridge regression.For that I used cross validation and grid-search technique in together. i got output result. I want check whether my regression model building  steps correct or not? can some one explain it?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
ridge_reg = Ridge()
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
params_Ridge = {'alpha': [1,0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001,0] , "fit_intercept": [True, False], "solver": ['svd', 'cholesky', 'lsqr', 'sparse_cg', 'sag', 'saga']}
Ridge_GS = GridSearchCV(ridge_reg, param_grid=params_Ridge, n_jobs=-1)
Ridge_GS.fit(x_train,y_train)
Ridge_GS.best_params_
```

**output - {'alpha': 1, 'fit_intercept': True, 'solver': 'cholesky'}**

```
Ridgeregression = Ridge(random_state=3, **Ridge_GS.best_params_)
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
all_accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=Ridgeregression, X=x_train, y=y_train, cv=5)
all_accuracies
```

**output -  array([0.93335508, 0.8984485 , 0.91529146, 0.89309012, 0.90829416])**

```
print(all_accuracies.mean())
```

**output - 0.909695864130532**

```
Ridgeregression.fit(x_train,y_train)
Ridgeregression.score(x_test,y_test)
```

**output - 0.9113458623386644**

Is 0.9113458623386644 my ridge regression accuracy(R squred) ?
if it is, then what is meaning of 0.909695864130532 value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the `score` method from Ridge regression returns your R-squared value ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.score)).

In case you are not aware how the CV method works it splits your data into 5 equal chunks. Then for each combination of parameters it fits the model five times using each chunk once as evaluation set, while using the remainder of the data as the training set. The best parameter set is chosen to be the set which gives the highest average score.

Your main question seems to be why the average of your CV score is less than the score from the full training evaluated on the test set. This is not necessarily surprising, since the full training set will be larger than any of CV samples which are used for the `all_accuracies` values. More training data will generally get you a more accurate model.

The test set score (i.e. your second 'score', 0.91...) is most likely to represent how your model will generalize to unseen data. This is what you should quote as the 'score' of your model. The performance on CV set is biased, since this is the data on which you based your parameter choices.

In general your method looks correct. The step where you refit ridge regression using `cross_val_score` seems necessary. Once you have found your best parameters from `GridSearchCV` I would go straight to fitting on the full training dataset (as you do at the end).

Comment: "Your main question seems to be why the average of your CV score is less than the score from the full training evaluated on the test set. This is not necessarily surprising, since the full training set will be larger than any of CV samples which are used for the all_accuracies values. More training data will generally get you a more accurate model."

I'm not clear your point? can you explain again it? my main question is steps which i followed are correct???

Comment: what is the difference of these two values? 0.909695864130532  and 0.9113458623386644 what value is my ridge regression score ??

Comment: I added some more details to my answer. I hope that helps. In general I think you are doing the right thing.

Comment: "In general your method looks correct. The step where you refit ridge regression using cross_val_score seems necessary. Once you have found your best parameters from GridSearchCV I would go straight to fitting on the full training dataset (as you do at the end)."                    That mean from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
all_accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=Ridgeregression, X=x_train, y=y_train, cv=5)             
all_accuracies

Comment: "The step where you refit ridge regression using cross_val_score seems necessary. Once you have found your best parameters from GridSearchCV I would go straight to fitting on the full training dataset (as you do at the end)."                    That mean from 
{ sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
all_accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=Ridgeregression, X=x_train, y=y_train, cv=5)             
all_accuracies  }  part is not necessary. I can directly run Ridgeregression.fit(x_train,y_train)
Ridgeregression.score(x_test,y_test) this two raw after GridSearch section.

Comment: As long as you initialize your RidgeRegression with the best parameters, then yes I think so:
`Ridgeregression = Ridge(random_state=3, **Ridge_GS.best_params_)`